# MS Exchange access by API or Web Services

Tags: web-services, powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am looking for a way to access emails in Exchange. I assume that there would be needed 2007 version with SP1. As I know there is possibility to access Exchange by PowerShell or by web services. What I am interested in is to access messages from various mailboxes to get their from/to/subject/body.

I've found that by web services this is possible by using FindItem and GetItem calls. Are there also other powershell commands to get to emails?

How can I access what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Exchange API for this (EWS) 
Glenn Scales has explained how to use it with powershell on  http://gsexdev.blogspot.nl/2012/01/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html?m=1

Answer (score -1):

I looked over the native [Exchange cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124413%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and was only able to find a reference to [Get-Message](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124738(v=exchg.80).aspx) cmdlet, but it appears that cmdlet is used to

> view the details of one or more messages in a queue on a computer that has the Hub Transport server role or the Edge Transport server role installed.

But it doesn't look like the message body is returned.

---

If you can tolerate a paid solution (currently in Beta), my employer (CData Software) makes a set of [cmdlets](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/exchange/powershell) for working with Exchange data.

EDIT: Beta solution isn't helpful for OP.

---

With the limitations in the native Exchange cmdlets and the restriction for a production solution, I can offer my employer's [ADO.NET Provider for Exchange](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/exchange/ado). We have already published a Knowledge Base [article](http://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/exchange-ado-powershell.rst) (whose contents are copied below):

The CData ADO.NET Provider for Microsoft Exchange implements standard ADO.NET interfaces, enabling you to access the capabilities of the Microsoft Exchange API from .NET applications, such as PowerShell. The provider simplifies authentication and interaction with Microsoft Exchange data. This tutorial shows how to use some of the common ADO.NET objects to execute SQL queries directly from PowerShell.

### Execute Queries

Follow the three steps below to execute any create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) command to Microsoft Exchange data in PowerShell:

1. Load the provider's assembly:

   ```
   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\CData\CData ADO.NET Provider for Microsoft Exchange\lib\System.Data.CData.Exchange.dll")
   ```
2. Connect to Microsoft Exchange data. Specify the User and Password to connect to Exchange. Additionally, specify the address of the Exchange server you are connecting to and the Platform associated with the server.

   ```
   $constr = "User='myUser@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com';Password='myPassword';Server='https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx';Platform='Exchange_Online';"
   $conn= New-Object System.Data.CData.Exchange.ExchangeConnection($constr)
   $conn.Open()
   ```
3. Instantiate the ExchangeDataAdapter, execute an SQL query, and output the results:

   ```
   $sql="SELECT GivenName, Size from Contacts"

   $da= New-Object System.Data.CData.Exchange.ExchangeDataAdapter($sql, $conn)
   $dt= New-Object System.Data.DataTable
   $da.Fill($dt)

   $dt.Rows | foreach {
     Write-Host $_.givenname $_.size
   }
   ```

### Update Microsoft Exchange Data

```
$cmd =  New-Object System.Data.CData.Exchange.ExchangeCommand("UPDATE Contacts SET BusinnessAddress_City='Raleigh' WHERE Id = @myId", $conn)
$cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.CData.Exchange.ExchangeParameter("myId","10456255-0015501366"))
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

### Insert Microsoft Exchange Data

```
$cmd =  New-Object System.Data.CData.Exchange.ExchangeCommand("INSERT INTO Contacts SET BusinnessAddress_City='Raleigh' WHERE Id", $conn)
$cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.CData.Exchange.Microsoft ExchangeParameter("myId","001d000000YBRseAAH"))
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

### Delete Microsoft Exchange Data

```
$cmd =  New-Object System.Data.CData.Exchange.ExchangeCommand("DELETE FROM Contacts WHERE Id", $conn)
$cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.CData.Exchange.Microsoft ExchangeParameter("myId","001d000000YBRseAAH"))
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Paid solution would be good if not in beta stage. Get-Message seems to get everything but body of the message. Also I need to access all accounts on Exchange server - not only one account.

Comment: So the paid solution is the better answer to the general question, but not specifically in your case? Just trying to figure out how to edit the answer.

Comment: I need a proper solution, third party software, especially in beta phase, is not an answer. Working solution and path to it is an answer.